# LARAVEL 5.2 -- Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: -- Problema relacionar tablas

Tags: php, laravel

Estoy intentando llenar unas tablas con la libreria faker, hasta ahora no he tenido ningún problema, puesto que eran miniproyectos y las tablas no estaban relacionadas, pero ahora, me estoy iniciando con las relaciones en laravel y me da un error que no consigo resolver.

Hay tres tables, libros users, y categoria

Este es el error:

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update
a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`laraveleloquentbasico`.`libros`, CONSTRAINT `libros_id_categoria_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`id_categoria`) R
EFERENCES `categoria` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE) (SQL: ins
ert into `libros` (`titulo`, `descripcion`, `id_categoria`) values (Animi.,
 Voluptate illo ut recusandae adipisci iure atque quasi. In hic dolorum tem
pora. Quos quidem et cumque non., 1))

[PDOException]
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update
a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`laraveleloquentbasico`.`libro
s`, CONSTRAINT `libros_id_categoria_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`id_categoria`) R
EFERENCES `categoria` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)
```

Despues de mucho investigar sé que es culpa del campo id_categoria que tiene la clave foranea, ya que intento rellenar ese campo manualmente, y me salta ese error, lo que no sé es lo que estoy haciendo mal.
La migracion la hace bien, el problema es al usar el db:seed, siempre sale ese error.
He intentado hacer ese campo fillable en el modelo, y entonces si que no puedo rellenar ningun campo del modelo, por lo que lo he quitado.
Aqui los codigos.

Migracion para crear libros

```
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreandoTablaLibros extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
         Schema::create('libros',function(Blueprint $table){
           $table->increments('id');
           $table->string('titulo')->nullable();
           $table->text('descripcion')->nullable();
           $table->integer('id_categoria')->unsigned()->nullable();

           $table->SoftDeletes(); //update at
           $table->timestamps();//create at, update at

           //RELACIONES

           $table->foreign('id_categoria')
                      ->references('id')
                      ->on('categoria')
                      ->onDelete('cascade')
                      ->onUpdate('cascade');

       });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
          Schema::drop('Libros');
    }
}
```

MIGRACION PARA CREAR CATEGORIAS

```
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreandoTablaCategoria extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
       Schema::create('categoria',function(Blueprint $table){
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('nombrecategoria');
            $table->timestamps();


       });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('categoria');
    }
}
```

MIGRACION PARA CREAR USUARIOS

```
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateUsersTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('nombre');
            $table->string('correo')->unique();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->enum('genero', array('f','m'));
            $table->string('bio');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('users');
    }
}
```

SEEDER PARA CREAR LIBROS Y USUARIOS

```
use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
use Faker\Factory;

class generaDatos extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        $faker = Faker\Factory::create();

        for ($i=1; $i <5 ; $i++) 
        {
        \DB::table('users')->insert(
                         array(
            'nombre' => $faker->name,
            'correo' => $faker->email,
            'password' => bcrypt('1'),
            'genero' => $faker->randomElement(array('m','f')),
            'bio' => $faker->text(255),


                            ));

         \DB::table('libros')->insert(
                         array(
            'titulo' => $faker->sentence(rand(1,5)),
            'descripcion' => $faker->text(rand(6,200)),
             'id_categoria' => $faker->randomElement(array('1','2','3')),

                            ));



        }


    }

}
```

SEEDER PARA CATEGORIA

```
use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

class CategoriaSeeder extends Seeder
{


   /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
         \DB::table('categoria')->insert(
                         array(
            'nombrecategoria' => 'PHP',
                       ));
              \DB::table('categoria')->insert(
                         array(
            'nombrecategoria' => 'HTML',
                       ));
                 \DB::table('categoria')->insert(
                         array(
            'nombrecategoria' => 'JAVASCRIPT',
                       ));
                    \DB::table('categoria')->insert(
                         array(
            'nombrecategoria' => 'CSS',
                       ));
    }
}
```

No pongo los modelos por que no tienen practicamente nada, pero si los necesitais los pondre

¿Alguna idea?

Comment: Asumo que el seeder de Categorías se ejecuta antes que el de libros y usuarios?

Comment: No, lo tenia al reves, lo he cambiado y ahora funciona, aunque no acabo de entender muy bien el por que. Me documentaré algo mas. Muchas gracias por tu ayuda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debes ejecutar el seeder de Categorias antes de los otros dos.

El error ocurre porque intentas asignar un valor a categoria_id sin que existan dichos id en la tabla de categoría, por lo cual la relación no se puede establecer.

Answer (score 0):

Para hacerlo todo relacionado y al mismo tiempo de la creación, puedes hacer:

Los users antes o después, no están relacionados, esos aparte cuando quieras.

Y las categorias y los libros en el mismo seeder, algo así como:

```
$id = DB::table('categoria')->insertGetId([...
```

Con esto va guardando el id al mismo tiempo que inserta, y en el mismo seeder cuando cierres categoria, abajo abres

```
DB::table('libros')->insert([<br>&emsp;&emsp;
           'id_categoria' => $id, ...
```

Así puedes crear en el mismo bucle "for" 100 categorias y 100 libros asociados a la vez

Espero que te sirva, no es 100% tu caso , pero sirve genial para usuarios y sus perfiles de usuarios por ejemplo.